# How to track install of another app via link

Tags: android

I have research little bit in Google and I found that Google analytics campaign allow tracking but it only for develop by me.

I want to track another app.

E.g. if send link of WhatsApp app to my friend and when my friend install app.
I want to track that WhatsApp app install from my link is unic or not.

And also receive some data that I know that install is done.

Basically I am thinking to develop app like wild wallet, earn talk time etc. Which allow user to install unic app and give them rewards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no method to do it.